# How to execute full text search command in MongoDB with Java Driver ?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

Mongo and Java gurus. Our team decided to use full text search API, introduced recently in MongoDB. However, we found some difficulties executing the command using the Java MongoDB driver.

here is my code I am using :

```
public BasicDBObject find(String search) {
    BasicDBObject searchCommand = new BasicDBObject();

        searchCommand.put("text", new BasicDBObject().append("search", search));

        CommandResult commandResult = db.command(searchCommand);
}
```

This is what I get when I print

```
 System.out.println(commandResult) 

{ "serverUsed" : "/127.0.0.1:27017" , "errmsg" : "exception: wrong type for field (text) 3 != 2" , "code" : 13111 , "ok" : 0.0 }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taken from a post on the Google group ( https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/7jWUbunUcFQ ):

```
    final DBObject textSearchCommand = new BasicDBObject();
    textSearchCommand.put("text", collectionName);
    textSearchCommand.put("search", textToSearchFor);
    final CommandResult commandResult = db.command(textSearchCommand);
```

Shows exactly how to format the command.