# MongoDB 3, java driver , full text search, how to?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver, nosql

You can see how to use full text search with java driver in mongodb 2

[how to use java driver with mongodb 2, full text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879109/how-to-execute-full-text-search-command-in-mongodb-with-java-driver/37355986#37355986)

but in mongodb 3 this does not work, anybody know how to do full text search with java driver/mongodb 3?

Comment: Who is voting this down? I am having this exact same issue and this question was helpful to me. Please propose an edit or leave a comment if you think this question should be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just work if you have index, in the mongodb 3 full text search integrated with find.

```
public List<ArticleData> doAdvancedSearch(String searchString) {
        List<ArticleData> list = new ArrayList<>();

        DBCursor cursor = collection.find(new BasicDBObject("$text", new BasicDBObject("$search", searchString)));
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject document = cursor.next();
            ArticleData data = new ArticleData();
            data.setContent((String) document.get("content"));
            data.setTitle((String) document.get("title"));
            list.add(data);
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was yet again different for me.

```
List<Document> list = new ArrayList<>();
FindIterable<Document> iter = collection.find(new BasicDBObject("$text", new BasicDBObject("$search", query)));

for (Document d : iter) {
    list.add(d);
}

return list;
```

I'm using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```